# Different customer types

Tags: commerce

Is it possible to have multiple customer types within Drupal commerce eg consumer and trade? These would then have different pricing stuctures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's just up to you to add the fields or roles to your user accounts and then write product pricing rules to adjust prices through a calculation (10% off for role X) or price swapping from whatever price fields you've added to the product type (base price for normal customers, price 2 for role X, price 3 for role Y). This is just pretty standard Drupal stuff combined with Rules.